# Saving and loading object which implements actionListener

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

I am saving some objects with ObjectOutputStream. When I am loading them with ObjectInputStream the actionListeners are not working. The Object are JPanels which can be dragged in the container. How can I make it work? There is not much to read about so I hope I can get some information here.

```
private void loadInputStream (String file) {

    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            mainPanel.removeAll();
            repaint();
            FileInputStream fip = new FileInputStream(file);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fip);
            if (ois != null) {
                while(fip.available() > 0) {
                    Component obj = (Component) ois.readObject();
                    mainPanel.add((Component) obj);
                    }
            }   
            ois.close();
        }catch (EOFException  e) {
                // Do Nothing   
        }catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}

private void saveChanges(String selectedWH) {

    try {

        String file = prop.get(warehousesFile, selectedWH);
        FileOutputStream fosTemp = new FileOutputStream(file+"temp");
        ObjectOutputStream oosTemp = new ObjectOutputStream(fosTemp);
        File oosOld = new File(file);

        int compCount = mainPanel.getComponentCount();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < compCount ; i++) {
                Component comp = mainPanel.getComponent(i);
                oosTemp.reset();
                oosTemp.writeObject(comp);
            }

            oosTemp.close();

            if (!oosOld.delete()) {
                System.out.println("error while deleting");

            }

            new File(file+"temp").renameTo(oosOld);
            repaint();

    } catch (IOException iex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using Anonymous Inner Listeners or defining your own?

Comment: I am defining my own

Comment: Don't get me started with java object serialization... a relic from an old, unenlighted age. (For more, if you are interested, search for the big-endian little-endian network/data issue)

Comment: You might want to think about using Jackson (or some other JSON serializer, like GSON) with a custom JSON to Java object translator.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Or use JAXB